# How can I change the Kotlin compiler version on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, quasar

In IntelliJ you can set the target Java version like this:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't see a place where I can do the same for Kotlin. This makes it not possible for me to use Quasar-Kotlin. I want to switch to M14 even though I have 1.0 beta installed. How can I change back?

After changing the `build.gradle` file back to M14 I am greeted with compilation errors in my project.

[image]

My `build.gradle`: https://gist.github.com/Jire/5b517fd767ad498bc18f

Comment: Please note that Quasar 0.7.4-SNAPSHOT (available on SonaType snapshots) [supports 1.0 beta now](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar/issues/132).

Comment: @circlespainter yes, I opened the issue. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Go to Intellij Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Kotlin Compiler.
Update **Language version** and **Api version** to the one you wish.

(You can also use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and type *Kotlin Compiler* to get to this preference)

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.IMHO no. of upvotes proof of the same.

Answer (score 15):

##### Precondition:

The compiler bundled to Kotlin plugin (IDE) must be greater or equal than external compiler (project) used for building modules. So update Intellij IDEA to be compatible with the most up-to-date plugins.

Help > Check for Updates

[image: Check for Updates]

*Note: If you do not have the most updated version in Language and API version you will not be able to see the latest version of the plugin.*

---

### 1- Install a new version of the compiler

- **Languages & Frameworks > Kotlin**

1. Check version:  `1.3.61`
2. Update channel: Early Access Preview 1.4x and press **Check again**
3. A new version 1.4-M3-xxx is available and press **Install**

- Invalidate Caches & Restart
- Observe in **Languages & Frameworks > Kotlin** that:

> You have the latest version of the plugin installed.

- **Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Kotlin Compiler**

1. Language and API version: Change from `1.2` To Latest stable `1.4-M3` *(if the Latest stable `1.4-M3` version do not appear, so update the IDE)*

Finally, check version in **Project Settings > Modules > Module SDK > Kotlin SDK**: `1.4-M3`

### 2- Update compiler version in project

I recommend is to synchronize gradle with a non-existent version in order to clean the external libraries. This is because it could happen that our libraries continue to use the old version of the compiler after updating.

1. For example: change from `1.4-M3` to `1.4.20-M1`

### build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4-M3" apply false 
}
```

2. It is important to synchronize with a wrong version like X to clean the external libraries with which we would get the following message.

### build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "X" apply false 
}
```

[image: Message]

3. Then we define and synchronize with the new version.

### build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.20-M1" apply false 
}
```

GL

[Kotlin versions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/eap-next)

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this at the moment. Building your project in IntelliJ IDEA always uses the version of the Kotlin compiler bundled with the plugin, regardless of what your build.gradle file says. If you need to downgrade to M14, you need to install the M14 version of the plugin.

Comment: How can I downgrade to the M14 version of the plugin?

Comment: I have v1.0.0-beta of the plugin installed and I am able to run his build.gradle without any problems.

Comment: To downgrade you'd have to manually install the plugin right? I wonder if I can build and you cant due to the gradle cache mentioned in your output? Maybe Yole can provide more insight.

Answer (score 2):

The kotlin versions are defined in your build.gradle file.

See the following example :

[build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/maarek/df972cac0165bf480bd7)

Comment: This is what I thought however I had changed the version to the latest M14 and it no longer will compile. `build.gradle` seems to specify the library version of Kotlin rather than the compiler.

My `build.gradle`: https://gist.github.com/Jire/5b517fd767ad498bc18f

Comment: Updated original question with image of build attempt.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest IntelliJ EAP and Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Try syncing gradle, gradle clean and if all else, deleting your build directory?

Comment: Tried and it did not work. @yole says that it's not possible yet and that I'd have to downgrade to the M14 version.

Answer (score 1):

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution & Deployment` -> `Kotlin Compiler`.

You should get something like in this image, and here you can change the version of Kotlin Compiler
[image]